# Django Rest Framework - Can't specify seconds on DateTimeField HTML form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using the Django REST framework and trying to POST a DateTimeField on the HTML form, I can write everything but the seconds.

Here is a printscreen that shows what I mean:
[image]

I've tried to update the serializer to:

```
timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference to [input formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS) and I think you can make your example work like this

```
DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't exactly works.
Now when I try to input a different format it says it's wrong but the form doesn't let me write seconds yet. It "truncates" all numbers after I write the minutes. Here: https://imgur.com/aD4bhOq